# A tricky query for finding new forum posts

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, forum

So I have these models.

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  has_many :forum_topics
end

class ForumTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  has_many :forum_topic_reads

  # has a :last_post_at date column 
end

class ForumTopicRead < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum_topic
  belongs_to :user

  # has a :updated_at date column
end
```

Very basic setup.

Now what I want to get is an arry of ids of forums that have unread posts sowhere in their subtree. The presence of new posts is decided by the comparescent of forum_topics.last_post_at with forum_topic_reads.updated_at where forum_topics.id = forum_topic_reads.forum_topic_id for a particular user_id or when a ForumTopicRead record is absent for that topic and user.

The problem is - the only way I managed to get it working is by manualy going through every forum and geting its subtree and then getting all the topics for the subtree etc. That results in a ton of similar queries to the database and thus a very slow process.

I believe there should be a way to make it go faster. I just need the ids of the forums that have at least 1 unread topic in their subtrees, don't need the count, don't need the topic ids themselves.

**UPDATE**

Got a hint from @MrYoshiji

This query:

```
ForumTopic.joins(:forum_topic_reads).where('forum_topics.last_post_at > forum_topic_reads.updated_at AND forum_topic_reads.user_id = ?', user.id).pluck(:forum_id).uniq
```

does not work quite well, 'cause it ignores the topics withought appropriate topic_reads (and creating a read for every topic for every user is a bit of an overhead)

**UPDATE 2**

So I finally came up with a promissing path. If I drop all the reads on a topic when a new post gets added to it (thus updating the `:last_post_at` field), I'll be able to collect the `forum_ids` with this query:

```
"SELECT distinct forum_id FROM `forum_topics` LEFT JOIN forum_topic_reads ON forum_topic_reads.forum_topic_id = forum_topics.id AND forum_topic_reads.user_id = #{user.id} GROUP BY forum_topics.id  having count(forum_topic_reads.id) < 1"
```

Now the only big problem I have is translating this from SQL to ActiveRecord.

Comment: Does this work? `ForumTopic.includes(:form_topic_reads).where('forum_topics.last_post_at < forum_topic_reads.updated_at')`

Comment: this might get the topics, but it would not get me close to getting the forum ids, because forums are a tree and those topics can be several layers below the root.

Comment: It would be also better to use `.joins` or `.eager_load` instead of `.includes`  here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ForumTopic.unscoped.joins(:forum_topic_reads).where('user_id = ?', user[:id]).group(:id).having('forum_topic_reads.count < 1').pluck(:forum_id)
```

Comment: emm..where did that `view_mappings.count` come from?

Comment: @Almaron Sorry about that, answer was base of some of my existing code. (copy paste)

Comment: but how does this query check the difference in time between the read and the topics last post?